# Nodejs adm-zip fails in Lambda with Access Denied Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My goal is to read a file inside a zip file from Lambda which is called by S3 Put, here is the code, but it fails Access Denied, even though Lambda has full access to S3:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
var fs = require('fs');  
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
    console.log('Bucket Name:', bucket);
    console.log('Object Name:', key);
    var buffer = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();   
    var zip = new AdmZip(buffer);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
    zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
        console.log(zipEntry.toString());
        console.log('File Name: ',zipEntry.entryName); 
        if (zipEntry.entryName == "text.txt") {
             console.log(zipEntry.data.toString('utf8')); 
        }
    });
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
START RequestId: fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6 Version: $LATEST
2016-07-18T20:48:33.983Z    fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6    Bucket Name: myTestBucket123
2016-07-18T20:48:33.984Z    fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6    Object Name: test.zip
2016-07-18T20:48:35.145Z    fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6    AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:524:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
END RequestId: fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6
REPORT RequestId: fc524797-4d28-11e6-a092-5b3299c063a6  Duration: 4318.87 ms    Billed Duration: 4400 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB  
Process exited before completing request
```

Here is the policy for the role that Lambda is using:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your Lambda function looks like it has the correct IAM role. What does the bucket policy look like on your S3 bucket? Also your question title is confusing because this has nothing to do with `adm-zip`. Your code is failing at the `s3.getObject` line before it ever gets to the `adm-zip` usage.

Comment: Any updates on this one? I am trying to update (add new files) to my existing zip on S3 with Lambda using adm-zip.